# How to use jsForce to call Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates()?

Tags: jsforce, findduplicates

I nedd do something like this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicates.htm#apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicates

I also find this: https://jsforce.github.io/document/#apex-rest

Can I use jsForce to call Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates()?   Or jsForce do not let you do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `findDuplicates` is only available through Apex, you must write a REST API in order to expose it.  Then you can make a call with the JSForce functionality you mentioned.  See [Introduction to Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_intro.htm) in the Salesforce documentation to get started on writing your REST API.